# Importing VCard in objective C in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.2, addressbook, vcf-vcard

I am developping an iPhone App using XCode 4.2 .in a portion of the App I will be getting a VCard as an NSString

I found this function i`nitWithVCardRepresentation` and i think it will be easier than parsing the data one by one (i.e getting the first name then the last name etc ... , but I have a hard time to implement it in my code .

I have the `AddressBook` and the `AddressBookUI` frameworks and I am trying to use this code but can t find an exact way to do it

```
-(IBAction)Add{

  // I have a  NSString *card defined somewhere else
   ABAddressBookRef *iPhoneAddressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    ABRecordRef *contact = ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation(iPhoneAddressBook, (__bridge_retained CFStringRef) card);

    CFRelease(contact);
    CFRelease(iPhoneAddressBook);   
}
```

when I compile ,it crashes  at the line 
`ABRecordRef *contact = ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation(iPhoneAddressBook, (__bridge_retained CFStringRef) card);`
and  I get the following green error in   the `@autoreleasepool`

```
Thread1:Program Received Signal "SIGABRT".
```

I am quite new to the Apps development , please let me know if the information I gave is sufficient

Thanks

Comment: Did you reach a solution? You are allowed to answer your own questions. If not where are you stuck now?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an ABPerson afterwards (what is advisable), use:

```
// Assuming NSString *card exists already.
ABPerson *person = [[[ABPerson alloc] initWithVCardRepresentation:[card dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```